# Fasttext Fatal Python error: Floating point exception in Docker gitlab runner test

Tags: python, docker, floating-point, fasttext

I'm doing a little test of a Fasttext wrapper in a docker runner. This is the test:

```
import fasttext
import tempfile

def test_fasttext_fit_save():
    x_clean = [
            "comment important one",
            "this is other comment",
            "this is other comment",
            "hi this is a comment",
        ]
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w+", suffix=".txt")
    for com in x_clean:
        temp.write(com)
        temp.write("\n")
    temp.seek(0)

    model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(input=temp.name,
        dim=3,
        epoch=25,
        lr=0.1,
        minCount=1,
        word_ngrams=1,
        bucket=2000000,
    )
    # Test save
    model.save("model.bin")
```

but, when run this in the gitlab docker runner I obtain:

```
test_fasttext_fit_save Fatal Python error: Floating point exception
```

and doesn't show more. When do this test in my computer installing the docker, this run good.

The docker file has this:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install fasttext
RUN pip install tempfile
RUN python -c "import fasttext; print(fasttext)"
RUN pip install pytest==6.0.1
RUN pip install pytest-cov==2.10.1
RUN pip install pytest-testmon
...
```

My computer has 4GB and the runner 1GB, but the test don't use 1GB of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a memory issue, not because the code you run actually requires it, but because fasttext (facebook) requires a minimum of RAM to correctly run things, for instance, this also happens with prophet.

A great alternative is to use gensim's implementation of fasttext.

Comment: What are the main differences between gensim fasttext Implementation and the original one? Edit: I see it supports continued training of a model that is pretty cool!